# how to use python to find consecutive lines

Tags: python

I have a file,like this:

```
the 1 file is:
none
the 2 file is:
a-h-f
the 3 file is:
a-h-p
the 4 file is:
none
```

I want to use python to know which two consecutive files are contend,not none.Take this file as example,"the 2 file" and "the 3 file" are continuous and have content.The result I expect is:

```
   the 2 file is:
   a-h-f
   the 3 file is:
   a-h-p
```

Please someone give me some tips.Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply use `grep -A 1 'the [23] file is:' ...` ? Why use Python at all? For that matter, it's even better suited to `grep` if you put the filename and content on one line. You can easily reformat your file into that format.

Comment: iterate the file two lines at a time. One approach could be a function that yields two lines at a time. It is then simple to check for the None value and discard some lines. To iterate two lines at a time look at the functions `iter`, `next` and the `StopIteration` exception.

Comment: @hruyu Please look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your lines in a list, i.e. could be `lines = f.readlines()` where `f` is a file object, or:

```
lines = '''the 1 file is:
none
the 2 file is:
a-h-f
the 3 file is:
a-h-p
the 4 file is:
none
'''.splitlines()
```

then:

```
for t in zip(*[lines[i::2] for i in range(4)]):
    if 'none' not in t:
        # t is ('the 2 file is:', 'a-h-f', 'the 3 file is:', 'a-h-p')
        # do something with it, e.g.:
        for x in t:
            print(x)
```

prints:

```
the 2 file is:
a-h-f
the 3 file is:
a-h-p
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of 4 consecutive  elements and filter those with none in it. Then party...

```
with open("input_file","r") as in_file:
    lines = in_file.read().split("\n")
consecutive_lines_4 = [lines[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(lines)-3),2]
result = [i for i in consecutive_lines_4 if 'none' not in i]
print(result)
```